# Send message after database update

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I'm using `django-channels` to provide a chat app on websockets. I store messages in a database. I would like to be able to send new messages to the client as soon as they get written to the database. How can I do that? I guess I need to make a `WebSocketConstructor` that will recieve a `post_save` signal, but I don't know exactly how to send signals to `django-channels` consumers.

Answer (score 1):

You can call this inside your WebSocket consumer

```py
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

@database_sync_to_async
def create_message(self, content):
    new_message = global_message.objects.create(
                  sender=self.scope['user'], 
                  content=content)
    new_message.save()
    return new_message
```

You can read more about it here: [Django channels docs: Database Access](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/databases.html#). Or you can look at my source code here: [ahmedyasserays/onlinechat](https://github.com/ahmedyasserays/onlinechat#)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the channel layer here like it's told [in the Channels docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#using-outside-of-consumers).

So in your `post_save` signal, you can send messages from the database to the channel layer (but the question of matching the message with a channel/group is open - I think some of this information should be saved in your database).